# How to generate HTML table based on group by?

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

I am trying to create very simple time tracking app with only 3 values in database: *description*, *time-spent* and *date* and I need to group results by Date and generate HTML tables.

For example:

Today(10.07) for this date I have 3 records in database, I need to generate HTML table for this date.

Tommorow(11.07) when I create new record with new date - it creates new HTML table.

At the and I have a lot of HTML tables with specific day dates.

(HTML table for its own date).

So how to group by date and how to generate HTML tables?

The screenshot below reflects what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: What i'm trying to achieve]

Below is my code:

```
function getLogs( $con ) {
  $stmt = $con->prepare( "SELECT * FROM timelogsapp GROUP BY DATE ORDER BY date DESC" );
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo '<table class="list-table">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<span class="date">';
    echo datetime();
    echo '</span>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Description</th>';
    echo '<th>Time</th>';
    echo '<th>Date</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['time'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the table and head tags from the loop. Only loop on table rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL `WHERE` the dates are within the wanted range. So you said you wanted to be for today, it would look like this:

### UPDATE

This should create multiple queries and you can Add more to the WHERE clause, to get the custom date, I hope this gives you an idea of what you can do with.

Every record will create it's unique table, as they are inside of the `foreach` clause.

```
<?php

$today = date('d.m');
$today_query = "SELECT * FROM timelogsapp WHERE date = $today DESC";

$yesterday = date('d.m', time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
$yesterday_query = "SELECT * FROM timelogsapp WHERE date = $yesterday DESC";

$custom = "";
if (isset($_POST['date']))
{
    $custom = $_POST['date'];
}
$custom_query = "SELECT * FROM timelogsapp WHERE date = $custom DESC";

$tom = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$tomorrow = $tom->format('d.m');
$tomorrow_query = "SELECT * FROM timelogsapp WHERE date = $tomorrow DESC";


function getLogs($con){
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM timelogsapp WHERE date = $today AND date = $yesterday AND date = $custom DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo '<table class="list-table">';
            echo '<thead>';
                echo '<span class="date">';
                    echo datetime();
                echo '</span>';
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<th>Description</th>';
                    echo '<th>Time</th>';
                    echo '<th>Date</th>';
                echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
            echo '<tbody>';
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['time'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
?>
```

Of course you can make that much more dynamic by playing with some PHP. But that will select all records from `timelogsapp` just where the dates equal to 10.07. Then display it in descending order.

Comment: You didn't really answer to my question on how to generate html tables. :) I can get today date with WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()

Comment: What do you mean? How do you need to generate the html tables? One for today, tomorrow, and whatever other dates?

Comment: Today, yesterday and previous days. Take a look at image above. :)

Comment: Let me know if the updated answer worked... I'm guessing that's what you're looking for

Comment: This looks more to what i need, but i get this error - Notice: Undefined variable: all_dates in ,  Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty in:

Comment: Where I had ```$all_dates``` change that to just the SQL command and see if that helps; that is what it seems to be saying. Otherwise the sql syntax may be wrong.

Comment: These queries are not properly implementing prepared statements.  You should not be injecting variables for values directly into the sql string.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the result i've been looking for.

```
 // getting all dates from database with limit
$all_dates_query = "SELECT * FROM timelogsapp GROUP BY date(date) ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
$stmt = $con->prepare($all_dates_query);
$stmt->execute();
$all_dates = $stmt->fetchAll();

function getLogs($con, $all_dates)
{
    foreach ($all_dates as $row) {
        $this_date = $row['date'];
        $all_dates = "SELECT * FROM timelogsapp WHERE date(date) = date('$this_date') ORDER BY date DESC"; //getting all logs for current date
        $stmt = $con->prepare($all_dates);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        //generating html table with logs
        echo '<table class="list-table">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<span class="date">';
        echo datetime($this_date);
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>Description</th>';
        echo '<th>Time</th>';
        echo '<th>Date</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['time'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime($row['date'])).'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Much of this answer should not be used by researchers.  Iterated queries should be avoided where possible.  Prepared statements should not be `prepare()`d inside of a loop, they should be declared only once and executed one or more times in a loop. You are not binding values to the stmt, you are introducing vulnerability/instability by writing a variable into your sql.  `fetchAll()` should not be iterated in the same layer.  If iterating the full result set, do not fetchall, but make iterated fetches.